# using google cloud storage api with developer key (not OAuth2)

Tags: php, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload file to google cloud from some console command. As I understand right, can't do it with OAuth2, so i need to use Api key. But nothing works. I tried this

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/temp/o?uploadType=media&name=p11&key='.$this->key;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: key '.$this->key
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '@/var/www/test.txt');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($content);
```

There is a error:

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", 
  "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ],
  "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } }
```

And i tried php-sdk

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("alasdg");
$client->setDeveloperKey($this->key);
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write']);
$client->getAuth();

$storageService = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
$buckets = $storageService->buckets->listBuckets('temp');
var_dump($buckets);exit;
```

The error is:

```
Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=temp&key=afJwBJWucqvIU: (400) Invalid argument.
```

Can i upload files without OAuth2?

Comment: You can upload files without authentication if the bucket already exists and allows public submissions (Bucket ACL with the entry allUsers have WRITER permission). However, then you're responsible for handling abuse yourself. There's also the legacy HMAC authentication support, but that only works with the XML API, not the JSON API whose URLs / SDK you mention above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Invalid Credentials` error implies that your `Authorization` header is invalid in some manner, and you need to refresh your OAuth 2.0 access token. Given that the API key is not a valid access token, that would explain it. You probably want to construct a header that looks like `Authorization: Bearer ya29.xxxxxxxx` where the "ya29" etc. is an access token. The credential exchange is done on your behalf by the php-sdk.

The second error you are getting because it is very likely that there is no project whose Project ID is "temp". It's a bit a of a gotcha, because you can assign a "friendly name" to your project, but that name can be shared among many projects and is not a unique identifier. You must either use the named Project ID, or, if you haven't assigned your project one, you can use the numeric Project ID, which is visible in the URL when you view it in https://console.developers.google.com/

Comment: Authorization header is invalid in some manner, and you need to refresh your OAuth 2.0 access token - can i get this token without user authentification before this query?

Comment: If you want to act as the user, not at the moment. If you want to act as a service account, then you can authorize a service account by using a signed JWT assertion; you'll need the service account's private key, and the SDK will help you with that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Read-write operations will always require proper authentication and authorization, i.e. OAuth2 token ([more info](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing)). With only API key you are limited to anonymous read-only API access (given that target resource is marked as public).

Comment: Strictly speaking, the API key allows anonymous API access. The underlying API governs what should happen for anonymous access, and GCS resources _can_ be set up to allow anonymous writes. It's not a best practice though, for obvious abuse reasons.