# Laravel: Google Cloud Storage and Google Compute Engine

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I need to store user data to my google cloud storage bucket.
I'm running laravel on google compute engine.

Could someone assist with this?
I've found only tutorials for google app engine so far.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-on-google-app-engine

Comment: @ceejayoz this is for app engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Cloud Storage JSON API is a simple, JSON-backed interface for accessing and manipulating Google Cloud Storage projects in a programmatic way.

You will need to use Google APIs Client Library for PHP to send requests to the Google Cloud Storage JSON API. See the links below for more info and examples:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples

Comment: I keep getting Error calling `GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=projectName&key=Key: (400) Invalid argument`.

I have configured everything from the second link.
Many thanks for help

Comment: Take a look at the link below and let me know if it resolves the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608235/using-google-cloud-storage-api-with-developer-key-not-oauth2